# Multiple Pipes in C

Tags: c, pipe

I looked over the internet but I could not find how to do triple or more connected pipe in C?

Comment: Which OS? Why don't you post the code of what you have tried, and we will try to help...

Comment: A pipe has two ends.  Use more pipes.

Answer (score 0):

If you use any linux distribution as your OS, you can use POSIX Threads and you can create pipe or fifo or something else.

Here is an example:

http://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/2008/01/23/piping-in-threads/

Answer (score 0):

First, you should clarify what you are trying to achieve.

The usual basic pipe is only defined by a reading end and a writing end (P1 --> P2). However, several extensions to that concept exist :

- a "T" pipe with one writing end and two reading ends (P1 --> P2 & P3).
- a bidirectionnal pipe (P1 <--> P2).
- etc.

What you call "triple or more connected pipe in C" can be easily implemented by using several basic pipes. It requires a bit of programming in C, but not so much.